# Invoking AWS Lambda with API Gateway sequentially

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, architecture, aws-api-gateway

I have two API endpoints as following and was planning to control their execution by CloudWatch (time), like the first one is executed then the second one will be executed after 10 min.

- /input -> The main function is to validate a JSON file and save it into DB. Also, it need to make a response of the status of a request to a user.
- /calc -> Based on the data in the database, it calculates something and puts a result to S3 as a CSV file.

If I want to execute both functions sequentially, what kind of approach should I take? The idea of executing the second one at the end of the first one came to my mind, but it is not elegant at all.

Any suggestions are appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider AWS Step Functions. You can use the service to sequence calls to Lambda as a series of steps.

> AWS Step Functions lets you coordinate multiple AWS services into serverless workflows so you can build and update apps quickly. Using Step Functions, you can design and run workflows that stitch together services, such as AWS Lambda, AWS Fargate, and Amazon SageMaker, into feature-rich applications. Workflows are made up of a series of steps, with the output of one step acting as input into the next.

See https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/

Answer (score 1):

You can use several approaches:

1. Simple way is to use SNS, where once first function is executed, it will put a message to SNS topic where the 2nd function is subscribed to. (However this might need some code changes on the 1st function depends on the trigger)
2. You may use Step Functions as well to trigger the 2nd function only after the 1st is completed. This will not required any code changes, but there are some other concerns such as monitoring and pricing. (Step functions might be expensive compared to SNS approach if you are dealing with high volume of executions)

Answer (score 1):

from my point of view, using [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) that will invoke these Lambda functions will a great fit for your use case. 
In this way, when the first Lambda function will finish will invoke the second one with the option to have error handling in case one of them will fail.

In addition, I do not fully understand why do you need the API gateway. you mentioned that

> ...first one is executed then the second one will be executed after
>   10 min.

The API Gateway has a max of 30 seconds timeout, maybe you should consider using CloudWatch event rule to invoke the Step Functions by Schedule

Comment: Well, API Gateway is used for the first one only as it is the entry point for data input. Thank you for your suggestion. I will take a look at AWS Setup Functions.